# How will I solve my problem : expected primary-expression before '>' token

Tags: programming

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = A0;
const int echoPin = A1;
// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

#include <moving.h>
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;

moving car(6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 11, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13); // setting up a new RC car with pins EN1, IN1, IN2, EN2, IN3, IN4, EN3, IN5, IN6, EN4, IN7, IN8

void setup() {
{
  for (int i=2; i<14; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
  servo.attach(10);
  servo.write(90);
}
{
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}
}

void loop() {
  if (distance) > 10; // this is the problem
  car.set_speed(127);
  car.forward();
  delay(3000);
  if (distance) < 10; // and this
  car.set_speed(0);
  car.forward();
  delay(600);
  car.set_speed(127);
  car.right();
  delay(700);
  car.set_speed(127);
  car.forward();
  delay(700);
}
```

Comment: `if (distance > 10)`. What should be in `if` condition? `;` after it is an empty command. I am sure you do not want to have a condition to execute an empty command. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/if/

Comment: @Juraj is 100% correct... Presumably `car.set_speed()` and `car.forward()` are meant to be executed conditionally? Otherwise, what is the point of the `if()` statement? Also, is the `delay()` meant to be part of the conditionally executed code? Or not?

Answer (score 2):

You need curly brackets around your if block.

```
if (distance > 10) { // this solves the problem
  car.set_speed(127);
  car.forward();
  delay(3000);
}
```

etc
Edit: Thanks to the commenter.

Comment: That is not sufficient.  The entire condition must be enclosed in parentheses `if (distance > 10) {`

Comment: Maybe you could expand upon your answer.  Your answer is a little terse. Which statements need to be contained in the `{}` block and why..? Also you need to fix your suggestion as per @Craig's comment.

Comment: @karlo: The error message refers to line 38, a badly-formed 'if' statement. You probably meant something like "if (distance < 10){ do something; } else { do somethingelse; }", but as written, it is not correct C or C++.